# Why does Bessel function in Scipy and EXCEL give different results?

Tags: python, excel, bessel-functions

I tried to use Scipy and EXCEL to calculate Bessel function, but they give different results. Do you know why? Thanks in advance.

Python code:

```
import scipy.special as ss


result = ss.k1(0.2155481626213)
print(result)
```

EXCEL (I use the OneDrive Excel web app of today's version)

```
=BESSELK(0,2155481626213; 1)
```

The result from Python is `4.405746469429914` 
The result from Excel is  `4,405746474969860`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error of the result is quite small, the complexity of the numerical calculations and the error propagation can cause the difference.

Side note:
even Wolfram Alpha got a different value:4.405746469430.

Answer (score 0):

As @HubertusKaiser says; the error is so small that we can assign it to rounding-errors/floating-points.

There's an excelent explanation why `0.1+0.2 != 0.3` for most computers [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0).
Now imagine doing a lot of those "wrong" floating-points calculations, you end up with the error difference you see